# Linkedin share api not picking up open-graph meta tags

Tags: linkedin-api

I am sharing an url "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/trend-tracking/jaitley-promises-robust-tax-regime-for-investors/articleshow/62741496.cms?utm_source=linkedin.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=TEST-LINKEDIN" via share api, but no image is picked up from the og:image tag (i.e. meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com" ).

But when i am trying to share the same url from linkedin admin page, it is picking up the image. This means that the image follows all the size-standards and other things required by linkedin.

Then why is the share api not picking up image url from the open graph tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you think your share is properly formatted, but it's not working, first thing I would do is head on over to the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/), which will examine your URL and look for problems.

But, your URL *does look right!*  Are you sharing like this, with proper URL encoding?

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Ftrend-tracking%2Fjaitley-promises-robust-tax-regime-for-investors%2Farticleshow%2F62741496.cms%3Futm_source%3Dlinkedin.com%26utm_medium%3Dsocial%26utm_campaign%3DTEST-LINKEDIN
```

Because this link works for me!  Take a look:

[image]

Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes on the same problem!  Hope this helps!